# How to get last element in postgresql Text?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a text of elements seperated by `,` as follows:

```
'{4,56,7,3,2}'
```

the amount of elemets is **unkonwn**.

How do I get the last element?
in the above example `2`

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('4,56,7,3,2', '^.*,', '')
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5160)**

**EDIT:**

Try

```
SELECT replace(replace(regexp_replace('4,56,7,3,2', '^.*,', ''),'{',''),'}','')
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5164)**

Comment: please see edit.. the string is '{4,56,7,3,2}' not '4,56,7,3,2'. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple text manipulation functions `LEFT`, `strpos` and `REVERSE`:

```
SELECT val,
     CASE WHEN strpos(REVERSE(val),',') = 0 THEN val
          ELSE REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(val), strpos(REVERSE(val),',')-1))  
     END AS last_element
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f3fef/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════╗
║      val       ║ last_element ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 4,56,7,3,2     ║ 2            ║      
║ 1,11111,23121  ║ 23121        ║      
║ 123            ║ 123          ║
║ (null)         ║ (null)       ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**EDIT:**

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(val, '{', ''), '}', '') AS val
    FROM tab
)
SELECT val,
     CASE WHEN strpos(REVERSE(val),',') = 0 THEN val
           ELSE REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(val), strpos(REVERSE(val),',')-1))  
     END AS last_element
FROM cte;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b3e0/4/0)**</kbd>

Comment: please see edit.. the string is '{4,56,7,3,2}' not '4,56,7,3,2'. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is indeed stored with the curly braces you can simply cast it into an array and pick the last array element:

```
select (elements::text[])[array_length(elements::text[],1)]
from the_table;
```

As you didn't include the table definition, I assumed the column is named `elements`.

If the column does **not** contain the curly braces, but just a comma separated list of values, you can still use this approach:

```
select (string_to_array(elements,','))[array_length(string_to_array(elements,','), 1)]
```